# Adding color scales to Cells containing numbers within text in Excel

Tags: excel

Consider the following excel sheet..

[image: Excel Screenshot]

As it can be seen, the table contains the names of students of Class XII, and the subjects and their respective marks arranged in descending order. I have made the table in such a way that when I change the Group name, then the names of students change automatically along with their marks. Now I need to add color scales to the marks, if it were just marks I can use conditional formatting, but since there is subject names also, normal conditional formatting doesn't work. And since the table keeps on changing each time the Group selection changes, I can't use static cell color fill as well. Can you suggest a way of using a heatmap coloring to the table based on the marks just like the color scales in conditional formatting?

Comment: Can't you just use conditional formatting with a formula to color the cells instead of choosing one of the pre built conditional formatting rules that rely on the cell value?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah not if the OP wants the typical color scales variations.

Comment: Do the subject names change depending on Student??

Comment: What formula can I use?

Comment: @teylyn yes, the marks are arranged in descending order, so the order of subject names get changed

Comment: @teylyn  I thought we could build a conditional formatting that sort of replicated the color scales.  I have been playing with it and it doesn't look like it is that flexible.  I really think it SHOULD work but maybe it doesn't after all....

Comment: Since it doesn't look like conditional formatting is possible, you could make a VBA script that was triggered on Worksheet change to recolor the cells on the fly but it is a lot of VBA.  If you want to try it I can have a go.

Comment: your sample data is not sorted by value, btw

Answer (score 0):

Color scale formatting only works with numbers, not text. You may want to separate the values, so the text and the number for a subject are in two different cells. Then you can use color scales.

It's never a good idea to mix different data types into a cell, because the result is always text and any numeric operation or evaluation will be impossible.

[image]